# How to prevent showing iOS notification alert during transition between pages in Xamarin.Forms App?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, notifications

Xamarin forms App run in Iphone 6. I have Screen 2 where, on a button click, I save data into backend and navigate back to previous page , say Screen 1.

My inference is if I receive a notification alert in between this navigation,then the alert popup will have a grey blank background. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Hi , when you receive a notification , you can have a try with adding a delay time(0.1 second) to show popup alert .

Comment: Could you please share your code of the alert? So we can suggest the best solution?